# Splitting an array in python using numpy library

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner in python and I want to know the purpose of  `[3,5]` in `np.split(x, [3, 5])`

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 99, 99, 3, 2, 1]
x1, x2, x3 = np.split(x, [3, 5])
print(x1, x2, x3)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3] [99 99] [3 2 1]
```

Comment: Have you already read [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[3,5] splits the numpy array at index 3 and 5. At index 3 we have 99 and at index 5 we have 3, so it has split the array on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Please start by reading the documentation when such issues arise. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy-split) you can see that `numpy.split` has `(ary, indices_or_sections, axis=0)` parameters. You pass `x` as first argument `ary` and `[3, 5]` as `indices_or_sections`. If you look at `indices_or_sections` parameter explanation you will notice that:

> If indices_or_sections is a 1-D array of sorted integers, the entries
>   indicate where along axis the array is split.
>
> For example, [2, 3]
>   would, for axis=0, result in ary[:2] ary[2:3] ary[3:]

So your code just split `x` on the third and fifth indexes along zero axis.

Comment: what about in the case where we just have a integer

Comment: @Murad Are you seriously? Read the documentation, there everything is written!

Comment: @LevZakharov some documentation here as well https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/?cb=1